# What XPath selects the next <tr> after a <tr> containing X?

Tags: xhtml, xpath

```
<tr>
 <td>Blah!</td>
 <td>X</td> <!-- TR containing X -->
 <td>Woot!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Useful Data, contents unknown</td> <!-- Select this TR -->
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Useless data</td> <!-- Don't select this or any subsequent TR -->
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>More crap I don't want</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>X</td> <!-- Another X -->
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Useful</td> <!-- Do select this one, since previous has X -->
</tr>
```

What XPath would return the `<tr>` immediately following the `<tr>` that contains X?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

ChaosPandion's and Martin v. Löwis's answers both work for the sample you give, but if you are asking for the *next* tr, then presumably in some cases there are further tr elements in same table. In which case, the answers will give all the following or following-sibling tr elements.

Also going by the headline question rather than the sample, the xpath should probably allow for the X being in a th cell instead of td. And I'm guessing that you'd only want the following tr if it is in the same parent (thead, tbody, tfoot).

So I'd go for

```
//tr[* = 'X']/following-sibling::tr[1]
```

Answer (score 25):

This should work.

```
tr[td/text() = 'X']/following-sibling::node()
```

Answer (score 14):

```
//td[.='X']/following::tr
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for finding the next element from your element. Keep increasing for every hop:

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'US Dollar')]/following::android.widget.TextView[1]
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.